# Finding the number of entries in ZipFile programmatically in android

Tags: java, android

I would like to find the number of entries in a Zip File programmaticaly.
Operating System is Android.

I have created a ZipFile like this:

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(path);
```

But somehow I am getting the following exception:

> ZIpException: EOCD not found:not Zip archive

Please help me getting rid of that problem.

This is my code to unzip file. How I can show progress of Unzipping operation?

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
            ZipEntry ze = null;
            int iIndex = 0;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                iIndex++;
                Log.d(TAG, "Unzipping " + iIndex + " " + ze.getName());
                try {
                    if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                        dirChecker(ze.getName(), location + SLASH);
                    } else {
                        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(
                                location + SLASH + ze.getName());
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                        int len;
                        while ((len = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            fout.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                        fout.close();
                        zin.closeEntry();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            zin.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "unzipping completed.");
```

Comment: *ZIpException: EOCD not found:not Zip archive*, the exception says the file is not a zip archive

Comment: But Iam able unzip it programmatically using ZipInputStream and ZipEntry classes. Its properly unzipping. I want to show the progress of unzipping operation. How to do that?

Comment: please add some more code and do not ask more than one Question, to keep it simple

Comment: I just want to find the total number of entries in Zip File programmaticaly in android

Comment: this is not how SO works. You have to give more code and explain, what you have got so far  what you have tried, if you tried debugging it, your basic concept behind this etc. ELSE you could get answers that are useless for you and the guy who answered wasted time....

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [ZipException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipException.html):

> This runtime exception is thrown by ZipFile and ZipInputStream when
>   the file or stream is not a valid zip file.

My wild guess would be that either your zip file is corrupt or your path is incorrect.

If your zip file is corrupt you should fix that.

You could check if the file actually exists by calling
`File file = new File(path);`
and only open the ZipFile if `file.exists()`.

Comment: he just wrote *But Iam able unzip it programmatically using ZipInputStream and ZipEntry classes. Its properly unzipping. I want to show the progress of unzipping operation. How to do that?*

Comment: @blackbelt so what? he has to create a new Question then. //Quote:"Kindly suggest me Why its giving such exception."

Comment: @FelixLahmer: Agreed. This changes the question too much.

Comment: Sorry guys,   I was referring to *But Iam able unzip it programmatically using ZipInputStream and ZipEntry*, so probably the issue is not related to a wrong path.. My mistake

Comment: FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
ZipEntry ze = null;
int iIndex = 0;
while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
iIndex++;
try {
if (ze.isDirectory()) {      dirChecker(ze.getName(), location + SLASH);
} else {       FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(     location + SLASH + ze.getName());
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int len;
while ((len = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {   fout.write(buffer, 0, len);}fout.close();    zin.closeEntry();
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
This is my code to unzip.

Comment: @suhask Please use the edit button under your question and try rewording your needs and put your code there.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you try to get the nextElement() and then read it from the zip file. You can keep a counter to the loop of Enumeration of type ZipEntry and then increment as we find more elements.

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(f);
try {
  for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zf.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    ZipEntry ze = e.nextElement();
    String name = ze.getName();
    if (name.endsWith(".txt")) {
         InputStream in = zf.getInputStream(ze);
    }
  }
} finally {
  zf.close();
}
```

You can read about more at [Reading zip file efficiently in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740214/reading-zip-file-efficiently-in-java)